# How to change python program files without administrative access?

Tags: python, exe

While learning pygame, I created a Snakes game. I have a **high_score.txt** file which stores the high score of player. When the player breaks a score record, his/her new record is written in this txt file with python's **open()** function. The script runs fine, there's no problem at all.

Now, I converted this script into an executable using **pyinstaller**. I didn't use one-file mode. The executable also runs fine. Then, I used INNO SETUP COMPILER to convert my executable into a setup file. After I run this setup, the files required to run exe are stored in a separate **Snakes** folder in *Program Files* folder in my computer's *C Drive*.

The problem now begins. When I run my newly installed game, it starts fine. But when I start playing it, whenever I eat an apple (the food of snake), the error pop ups: **Unable to run script main**. After some debugging, I came to know that this error is coming because python is unable to rewrite the **high_score.txt** file to store the new high score, because the writing access is denied in Program Files folder. If I run my game as an administrator, then it runs fine. But I want this game to run properly without administrative access. I have researched it about on the Internet very much but nothing could help me. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: You should put this file in the user's directory, not a system directory.

Comment: this sounds like a good use for [`%APPDATA%`](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/appdata-where-to-find-the-appdata-folder-in-windows-10/#:~:text=The%20AppData%20folder%20includes%20application,where%20your%20important%20files%20reside.). Try storing your `high_score.txt` in there?

Comment: @Barmar I can't! The setup automatically stores all the files in system directory. The user manually can select a different directory while setting up the game, but why one would do so?

Comment: @khuynh May you please tell me little more about it? It's new for me.

Comment: @DivyanshuTiwari see my link above , you can access `%APPDATA%` as an environment variable (assuming you are on windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store this in the appropriate user directory, not the install location. Use [`Path.home`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.home):

```
from pathlib import Path
score_file = Path.home()/"Saved Games"/"My Cool Game"/"high_score.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. Your answer and khuynh's comment would help me a lot on future projects.